# How to store contract state as singleton?

Tags: smart-contract, persistence, persistence-api, singleton

What is the best way to store fields specific for contract, for example if contract has 3 fields (2 strings, 1 uint64_t) and they can be changed?
Should I create new table for this, it would always be one entry basically with 3 fields? I heard about singleton but can not figure out how to do it, maybe some example?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is only one instance to be created, I agree you should use a singleton for your case instead of a table directly, as this is what singletons are used for.

For API, you can check the [`eosio/singleton.hpp`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/blob/master/libraries/eosiolib/contracts/eosio/singleton.hpp) file, and here's a quick example using a singleton:

```
#include<eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include<eosio/singleton.hpp>

class singleton_example : eosio::contract {
    public:
        singleton_example(account_name account) :
            eosio::contract(account),
            singleton_object(_self, _self)
            {}

        void store(account_name account, uint64_t value1, uint64_t value2) {
            require_auth(account);
            singleton_object.set(sing{value1, value2}, account);
        }

        void get(account_name account) {
            require_auth(account);
            auto results = singleton_object.get();
            eosio::print(results.value1, results.value2);
        }


    private:
        struct sing {
            uint64_t value1;
            uint64_t value2;
        };

        typedef eosio::singleton<"singleton"_n, sing> single;

        single singleton_object;
};

EOSIO_ABI(singleton_example, (store)(get))
```

Comment: Nice! I wasn't aware that there was already an implementation of that abstraction.

Comment: EOSIO.CDT 1.5 singleton now requires uint64_t for the second parameter of the constructor. There's no direct conversion from the name object to it. Just change the constructor to: `singleton_object(_self, _self.value)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you're saying, it should simply be a single table with a single row that contains your data as a struct with the 3 fields.

You would need to define your struct and table as something like this:

```
//@abi table state i64
struct state {
    string field1;
    string field2;
    uint64_t field3;

    // Set the primary key to a constant value to store only one row
    uint64_t primary_key() const { return 0; }
};
```

And then you can use it inside an action like this:

```
state_table s_table(_self, _self);

// Write to the state for the first time
s_table.emplace(_self, [&](state& row) {
    row.field1 = "something";
    row.field2 = "something else";
    row.field3 = 1234;
});
// Update the state
s_table.modify(state_table.begin(), 0, [&](state& row) {
    row.field1 = "something new";
    row.field2 = "some other thing";
    row.field3 = 12345;
});

// Read from the state
state saved_state = s_table.get(0, "Error message for when state is not set yet");
```

Comment: No problem, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer Andreas Berrios. As of EOS CDT 1.3 release, the syntax has changed. I updated the code:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] state_struct {
    std::string field1;
    std::string field2;
    uint64_t field3;

    // Set the primary key to a constant value to store only one row
    uint64_t primary_key() const { return 0; }
    EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(state_struct,(field1)(field2)(field3))
};
typedef eosio::multi_index<"tablename"_n,state_struct> s_table;

s_table state_table(_self, _self.value);

// Write to the state for the first time
state_table.emplace(_self, [&](state_struct& row) {
    row.field1 = "something";
    row.field2 = "something else";
    row.field3 = 1234;
});
// Update the state
s_table state_table(_self, _self.value);
state_table.modify(state_table.begin(), _self, [&](state_struct& row) {
    row.field1 = "something new";
    row.field2 = "some other thing";
    row.field3 = 12345;
});
// Read from the state
state_struct saved_state = state_table.get(0, "Error message for when state is not set yet");
```