# A contract without struct and multi index table

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index

Actually, I am looking to create a contract in which a variable can be set and later on can be retrieved. All the contracts available there involves `struct` and multi index table.
In EOS, is it possible to write a smart contract without using `multi-index` table and `struct`?

Comment: You could delegate the storage of your state to a different contract. Does that count?

Comment: That is another thing, I am looking to know something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i know you cannot do that because multi-indexed tables are made to store all states and data,a variable will not store that.Because during transaction it stores only transaction data not your variable state that you might have seen in ethereum blockchain because ethereum have that structure that you can store state in transaction and eos have different structure that cannot used to store data in transaction.

Comment: You seem right.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is a singleton.

This answer explains how to use it well: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/1670/959

Comment: In the shared answer, logic is almost fine but they too are using struct and multi-index. I am looking to know the limitations of smart contract development in EOS.